# Error al generar código con Scaffolding en ASP.Net

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-5, controller

Me estoy aventurando en el mundo de ASP.Net, estaba tratando de generar un controlador con la ayuda del generador de código VS, pero cuando hago clic en "Agregar", aparece el siguiente error:

[image: Error al ejecutar el generador de código seleccionado: "Ocurrió un error al obtener el tipo 'WebApp.Models.Pelicula'. Intente volver a generar el proyecto".]

Los parámetros de configuración que he usado son los siguientes:
[image: The configuration parameters]

Espero que me puedas ayudar a resolver mi duda.

PD: Respecto a la sugerencia que me da VS, no sé cómo regenerar el proyecto.

Comment: Alejandro, este es el sitio en español. Traduce tu pregunta al español para ayudarte.

Comment: Listo, ¿me puedes ayudar ahora?

Comment: no se si ya solucionaste el problema, pero intentaste realziar un rebuild de la solucion, estas seguro que tienes un contexto de datos? porque recuerda que esto hace referencia a entity framework

Comment: [Te he votado negativamente porque solo pusiste una imagen de tu excepción](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2873/)

Comment: @LeandroTuttini no he logrado resolver el error y tampoco he intentado hacer el rebuild, pero ya luego intento, sobre el Contexto de datos, se supone que la opción que he seleccionado es una por defecto que te sugiere VS y que posteriormente crea, pero intentaré hacer rebuild

Comment: pero estas usando entity framework ? mm no entendi eso de "posteriormente crea", el mapping de la entidad debe hacerse antes

Comment: @AlejandroMejia por favor vuelve a leer el artículo, especialmente la parte que dice: **no todas las personas tienen la capacidad visual, es decir, una persona con debilidad visual o sin la facultad de la visión le será imposible conocer la traza de la excepción y por lo tanto, no podrá ni ayudarte ni recibir ayuda.**

Comment: @LeandroTuttini ya logré hacer el rebuild de la solución, y ya anduvo bien, lamento no haberlo intentado antes, me confundí al leer "regenerar", no lo tomé como sinónimo de "recompilar", gracias por su ayuda

Answer (score 3):

Parecerá tonto, pero he ahí la importancia de expandir nuestro léxico, en el mensaje del error decía "Intente regenerar el proyecto", lo que yo no comprendí en ese momento, es que con "regenerar" se refiere a hacer "Rebuild" o "Compilar" nuevamente la solución, fue gracias [Leandro](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/2600/leandro-tuttini) que caí en cuenta que tenía que compilar nuevamente la solución. Como dije, estoy incursionando en ASP.Net y no manejo el IDE al 100%,espero que a alguien más le sirvan mis fallos para no cometerlos, gracias a todos

Comment: Saludos bro, toma, te será de mucha utilidad: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6LZG76aLykY